# Any simulator is available for Java card with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, simulation, javacard

I am new to Java card programming. Any help for the following issue will be appreciated.

Installing of JCOP tools along with eclipse is completed.
I am able to run sample applications and send command using JCOP shell.

But I am unable to run my own created project's script file or find any simulator for testing purpose. Is there any way to communicate between sample applet and simulator?

Any resources to write commands in run.jcsh also would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: What do you mean regarding being able to run your own "applications"? Do you mean Applets? How do you run them without using the simulator? JCOP comes with a (set of) simulators (`jcop.exe`) and image files. I'm afraid you have to be more clear.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for the quick reply. I will elaborate the procedure I followed and  
would be helpful if you could throw more light on the same.I am using eclipse version  
 3.8.2 and NXP JCOP tools version 3.4.0. After completing updating eclipse and  
installing JCOP tool, I started with a sample Java card application by selecting  
following  **A)** API's to be added to class path *1)* Java Card Classic 2.2.2, *2)*  
Global  Platform 2.1.1 and *3)* JCOP Extended API 2.4.2 R3  **B)** Template selection ,  
selected Basic Java Card applet then given package name and applet name

Comment: **C)** After this got AID settings with options to input Package AID(given value:0x00:0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08:0x09:0x00) and Applet AID (0x00:0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08:0x09:0x00:0x00:0x00) **D)** Now in eclipse SampleApplet class is extended with Applet(javacard.framework.Applet) **E)** Now I am running this as a Java card application. **F)** Now JCOP shell opens up where I can enter commands like run. But once entering run its giving "jcshell: No such command: run". **G)** To be precise I cant find any simulator or the way to interact with applet

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issues with JCOP?

Comment: @owlstead : The JCShell opened up itself was the simulator and as you told JCOP manuals did helped me a lot. A script should be added into "script" folder and should be mentioned in run configurations. Now in jcop shell i can directly run the script by giving the script file name. Thanks a lot for the guidance. (I am not aware how to vote for you as you helped me to resolve the issue?)

Comment: You can actually vote on comments and answers, but only with enough rep. I'll give you some more reputation by upvoting your question. I've posted my comment as an answer, which can be accepted if this sufficiently solved your issues.

Comment: @Harry May I have your email address? I want to ask you something that is off-topic here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to see the TCP port being used from the `jcop.exe` process in the debugger, although it is easier to configure it to run on the default port 8050 (it uses a random port by default). It is then possible to open a connection using `/term Remote` in the shell. This is explained in the JCOP manuals from integrated in Eclipse help. It may be possible to use `/term Remote localhost:[port]` if you are not using the default port, but I may be wrong on the details of the command, as I always use the default port.

[initialy posted in the comments section]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at jCardSim, it is our open source product. You can easily integrate it with any project. For details see http://jcardsim.org

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve the issues I faced with eclipse JCOP tools itself.